# Splitting strings in a column into multiple rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','c'],'col2':['x1;x2;x3','x5','x6'],'col3':['y1','y2,y3,y4','y5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to choose a column and split that into multiple rows, for instance if I choose `col2` I expect the result to be the output of the following:

```
d = {'col1':['a','a','a','b','c'],'col2':['x1','x2','x3','x5','x6'],'col3':['y1','y1','y1','y2,y3,y4','y5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

and if I choose `col3` I expect:

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','b','b','c'],'col2':['x1;x2;x3','x5','x5','x5','x6'],'col3':['y1','y2','y3','y4','y5']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Note that in `col2`, `x` are separated by `;` while in `col3`, `y` are separated by `,`. I have tried `.explode` but that did not give the results I've shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df=df.replace(regex=r'[^\w]',value=',')#replace any punctuation with comma
df=df.assign(col2=df['col2'].str.split(',')).explode('col2')#Explode column2
```